# Measurable function approximated by Borel Function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space.

I had to prove the following:

**For every measurable function $f$, there exists a Borel measurable function $g$ such that $f = g$ a.e.**

This is what I did:

Let $(r_{n})$ be the enumeration of rationals. consider

$$ A_{n} = \{ x \in X \; | \; f(x) < r_{n} \} $$

Now choose a $G_{\delta}$ set $G_{n}$ such that $G_{n} \supseteq A_{n}$ and $\mu(G_{n} - A_{n}) = 0$. Let us call $C_{n} = G_{n} - A_{n}$. Redefine $f$ on $C_{n}$ by requiring $f(x) < r_{n}$ for $x \in C_{n}$. Call the new function $g$. Now

$$ \{ x \in X \; | \; g(x) < r_{n} \} = G_{n}$$

Thus, $g$ is measurable and differs from $f$ only on a set $C = \cup_{n}C_{n}$ of measure zero.

Am I right in what I did or did I make a mistake?

Comment: I'll assume that your measure space is $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}, m)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on reals and $m$ is Lebesgue measure. In your proof, when you say redefine $f$ such that $f \upharpoonright C_n < r_n$, you need to note that since $C_n$'s are not disjoint, a little more explanation is needed here.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $f$ can we written as a pointwise limit of simple functions (linear combinations of Lebesgue measurable sets), by 
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n2^n-1}\frac{j}{2^n}\chi_{A_{n,j}}+n2^n\chi_{B_n},$$ 
where $A_{n,j}:=\left\{x,\frac j{2^n}\leqslant f(x)\lt \frac{j+1}{2^n}\right\}$ and $B_n:=\{x,f(x)\geqslant n2^n\}$. Here we assumed without loss of generality that $f$ is non negative.

Then we use the idea  suggested in the OP: we write 
$$g_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n2^n-1}\frac{j}{2^n}\chi_{A'_{n,j}}+n2^n\chi_{B'_n},$$
where the outer measure of $A'_{n,j}\setminus A_{n,j}$ and $B'_n\setminus B_n$ is $0$, and $A'_{n,j}$, $B_n$ are Borel sets containing respectively $A_{n,j}$ and $B_n$.

Comment: And then we let $g$ to be the limit of $g_{n}$ and then $g$ is the required Borel function? But is it obvious that $g$ will be Borel measurable?

Comment: and by the way, where did I make mistake?

Comment: Since the $A'_{n,j}$ are chosen to be Borel (as well as $B_n$), $g_n$ is Borel measurable, and so will be the limit.

Comment: @Maverick You have to prove that your function $g$ is well-defined. (it's maybe not wrong, but it need details)